# What options do I have for storing information on Windows? How should I read this information?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

what options I have for storing information on Windows?

I was thinking of creating a file or working with the registry but the file could get rather annoying to handle if it gets too big and the registry is a bit too easily accessible by the user.

I don't expect there to be more than a max of 100 entries and they would look something like this.

*John Banana*

*Marcus Apple*

etc.

I realize this wouldn't produce a too big file but I dont want to parse it everytime I need the information. I was thinking of reading the information into the application on startup but wouldn't that create performance issues? Or perhaps it's so little it wouldn't matter except for older computers? Are there any other options? Perhaps I could encrypt the information and put it in the registry? Is the registry suitable for putting multiple entries such as this?

*Note that when I program I sometimes go a bit too overboard when it comes to making things efficient. Excuse my ignorance.*

Comment: When in doubt, use an embedded database stored in the user's profile. (SQLite, SQL Server Compact, VistaDB, etc.) It might be overkill, but it's a proven approach and easy to extend.

Comment: File is exactly as accessible as registry. Typical user has no idea what registry is, neither he/she looks into %APPDATA%. I'd go for a file, as this somewhat avoids using platform-specific APIs (but this is a matter of taste).

Comment: @millimoose I am not sure what you mean by "...embedded database stored int he user's profiles." I tried googling it but maybe I'm using the wrong keywords, care to provide a link?

Comment: Why are you scared of parsing 100 strings from a file? Have you arrived here in 2012 in a time machine? Is it 1963 where you are from? Reading 100 strings takes zero time.

Comment: @David Heffernan True true, would it better to read the information everytime I need it or just simply store it inside the application during runtime? Again, maybe this is no big deal either way.

Comment: If you are just reading/writing sequential data then a file is the way to go. If you expect to need random access to the file or want to update the middle of the file without wanting to write out the whole thing over again, then a file-based database like sqlite3 is the way to go. The Registry is never the right answer, imho.

Comment: @Root An embedded database is a database that doesn't run as a separate server, but that opens the database file "inside" your program. (I.e. doesn't require the server to be installed and set up separately.) By "the user's profile" I meant the home folder, or preferably an app-specific folder under %APPDATA%. I also wouldn't worry about whether the user can access the file. It's their computer, their data, and if they want to break it they're free to do so. Putting it under %APPDATA% should be a strong enough hint that you're not meant to mess with the files.

Comment: @mcl So, reading the contents of the file into my application WOULD be a performance issue? I was thinking along the lines of reading the file to some variable , editing it during runtime and then writing it back when terminating the application.

Comment: @Root: this (reading into memory at startup and updating the file at shutdown) is the usual strategy nowadays. It has really imperceptible performance impact.

Comment: @Root, if it's a short file (like only 100 lines), the *only* reason not to use a flat file and wait to write out the updated file at termination would be a concern about data loss if the program terminated abnormally. In that case I would probably just write out the file any time it was updated. 100 lines as you've shown is *extremely* minor amount of I/O and data processing.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Parsing 100 strings from a file doesn't take zero time.  It probably takes between 20ms and 100ms or so depending on how the file is parsed (and can take up to 1 second if the disks need to be spun up).  For most UI applications, that may not be significant but it's not "zero time".  And yes I'm being pedantic.

Comment: @LarryOsterman Well yes, I was being a little dramatic.

Comment: Is there not some std templated string vector with a 'loadFromFile()' method? Surely there is?  Also, 20-100 ms seems awfully slow, even for a spinner, (as long as it's actually spinning, yes). On an SSD...

Comment: @Root Hello, why don't you just try to implement the file solution and only after that measure the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked *What options do I have for storing information on Windows?* Basically, there are three main strategies:

1. Use the machine's Registry and use the Registry API to access it.
2. Use a flat text file in the [INI File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and use the Private
   Profile String API to access it.
3. Use a flat text file of your own format and use your own file
   handling to access it.

Any of these strategies will achieve your goal of storing data.

However, on Windows platforms, there is a more important question you must consider that will give you your answer:

> *Is the User of my application going to want to move their data to another machine and run my application on that other machine?*

If the answer is **Yes** to the above question, then (2) or (3) will be your answer as moving a file on disk from one machine to another is a simple task. Moving registry entries from machine to machine, on the other hand, is not a simple task for a normal computer user, and neither is the task of coding functions in your application to export registry databases to flat files and re-import them.

Within (2) and (3), (2) is the simplest as [Windows has existing APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the contents of the file out for you; (3) requires you to write your own routines. Ultimately, it will be reliant on how you want to structure your data.

If the answer is **No** to the above question, then any of (1), (2), or (3) is Ok as the user won't care how the data is stored.

None of the above strategies are less or more accessible than any other (if you're worried about user being able to view your data). If your worried about your data being visible then add encryption into the method you finally choose.